# Does android have a scope bar similar to IOS?

Tags: android, searchbar

Does android have scopebar like IOS? any idea how to build it? the only option i can think about is manually using xml draw the layout

any more stylish and more convenient way to build search scope bar or option? i wish some search by certain column instead of search all.

thanks

Comment: It's regular EditText + DB + ListView or http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: Android [Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) and [Quick Search Box](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introducing-quick-search-box-for.html)